# Phone takes up to 20 secs between click on phone number and actual call, receive multiple times the same sms

Tags: bugs, htc-one

My phone is behaving oddly and I don't understand what is going on.

It started a few days ago. When I click on a phone number or a contact (that link to his phone number to call directly), the list of last called number is correctly updated, the click is effective, but the actual call begins about 20 seconds later ! If I click multiple time on the phone number, it will call this number multiple times, but after the laps of 20 seconds.

Moreover, I found another bug that started the same day. When someone sends me an sms, I receive it multiple times, like 10/15 times, throughout the day (not at once). It's like I receive a new sms every hours, but it's still the same.

I didn't installed any new app or didn't make any update of the OS just before.

I tried to reboot the phone but the problem is still here.

I'm wondering if it's a hardware issue that makes android buggy, or an update of an existing app that makes it behaving that way.

Here the list of installed apps :

- 9Gag
- Barcode Scanner
- GMail
- Google+
- Prey Anti Theft
- Andmade share
- Dropbox
- Endomondo (pro)
- Facebook
- Google Authenticator
- Google Drive
- Google Play Kiosque
- Google Play Musique
- Hangouts
- Headspace
- Jewels Star
- Maps
- Google Chrome
- Profile Flow
- Google Search
- Vocal search
- Skype
- Street view
- Super Sudoku
- Twitter
- Youtube

It's an HTC One, and I didn't rooted it or installed a specific ROM, it's the OS from the purchase.

Thank you for your help !!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is probably the last thing you want to do but a factory reset is probably the best thing to try.

Comment: I'm starting to think about it yeah :/